# Stopping criteria for Llama-2 does not work

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, llama

I'm using LLama-2 13B with the following stopping criteria:

```
stop_words = ["Human:", "Chatbot:", "###"]
stop_words_ids = [tokenizer(stop_word, return_tensors='pt')['input_ids'].squeeze() for stop_word in stop_words]
stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([StoppingCriteriaSub(stops=stop_words_ids)])
generation_config = GenerationConfig( ... stopping_criteria=stopping_criteria )
prompt = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', truncation="only_first", max_length=4096)
prompt = {key: value.to("cuda") for key, value in prompt.items()}
out = model.generate(**prompt, generation_config=generation_config)
res = tokenizer.decode(out[0])
```

The model does not stop at the provided stop words. For example, if I have a response of the model `I'm feeling good, how about you?### Human: I'm also feeling good.### Chatbot: That's good.` the model should stop generating at the first `###`.

Why does this not work and how can this be fixed?

I have fine-tuned the model (with Axolotl) on a dataset so that the model produces responses as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

implementing working stopping criteria is unfortunately quite a bit more complicated, I'll explain the technical details at the bottom. You have to make a child class of StoppingCriteria and reimplement the logic of it's `__call__()` function, this is not done for you and it can be implemented in many different ways.

Luckily, there's some code I was able to piece together that seems to work well.

I wrap this up into a simple interfacing function, because it will look kind of gross if you keep piling stuff sequentially:

```py
from transformers import StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList
from torch import cuda, LongTensor, FloatTensor

def create_stopping_criteria(stop_words, tokenizer, device):

    class StoppingCriteriaSub(StoppingCriteria):
        def __init__(self, stops = [], device=device, encounters = 1):
            super().__init__()
            self.stops = stops = [stop.to(device) for stop in stops]

        def __call__(self, input_ids: LongTensor, scores: FloatTensor) -> bool:
            last_token = input_ids[0][-1]
            for stop in self.stops:
                if tokenizer.decode(stop) == tokenizer.decode(last_token):
                    return True
            return False

    stop_word_ids = [tokenizer(stop_word,
                               return_tensors="pt", 
                               add_special_tokens=False)["input_ids"].squeeze() 
                               for stop_word in stop_words]

    stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([StoppingCriteriaSub(stops=stop_word_ids)])
    return stopping_criteria
```

Then, to use this function, you can pass in a list of words you wish the model to stop on:

```py
device = f'cuda:{cuda.current_device()}' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
stop_words_list = ["###"]
stopping_criteria = None
if stop_words_list is not None:
    stopping_criteria = create_stopping_criteria(stop_words_list, tokenizer, device)

# When it's time to generate
input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to(device)

output = model.generate(input_ids,
                        stopping_criteria=stopping_criteria # Pass stopping criteria
                        )

response = tokenizer.batch_decode(output[:, input_ids.shape[1]:], skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
```

Unfortunately, choosing your stop words passed also needs to be adjusted and tested. Tokenization is weird, and while you probably didn't fine-tune the tokenizer, some things may still be tokenized differently depending on how it is placed within the sentence. For example, "###", " ###", and "### " may all be different tokens depending on how they are placed in the sentence, and you may have to pass all of them into your `stop_words_list`. Spaces or newlines or even other characters before or after each of your stop words can make it into an entirely different token. Experiment with a few and see what works!